# Not getting response in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get ajax response. But my code does not show anything in alert. Here is my ajax code. my form id is **contact_form** and my submit button id is **submit_btn**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#contact_form').on('submit', function(e){ 


       var form= $("#contact_form").val(); 
         $.ajax({
                type      : 'POST',
                url       : 'email.php', 
                data      : form.serialize(), 
                dataType  : 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                   alert(response);                

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   //console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }


        });

         e.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

my email.php

```
<?php

   echo "ok";

?>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: `ok` is not valid JSON, so you're getting an error. Try `echo json_encode("ok");`

Comment: Or change it to `dataType: "text"`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: form.serialize is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is because you are trying to use the serialize method in a wrong way.

The [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) method will handle all the fields that are inside the selected target form. In the original code, You've used the [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method to take the values of the form, but this will not work because that method is intended to be used with a single form element and can't handle the whole form.

Change your code in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#contact_form').on('submit', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();   
    var form = $("#contact_form"); 
         $.ajax({
                type      : 'POST',
                url       : 'email.php', 
                data      : form.serialize(), 
                success: function (response) {
                   alert(response);                
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
        });
   });
});
```